# How can I write a conditional lock in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

The thing is I've been using the [lock statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx) to protect a critical part of my code, but now, I realize I could allow concurrent execution of that critical code is some conditions are met.
Is there a way to condition the lock?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Action doThatThing = someMethod;

if (condition)
{
  lock(thatThing)
  {
     doThatThing();
  }
}
else
{
  doThatThing();
}
```

Comment: Clarification:  most answers here are about conditionally entering the lock based on whether or not you want to doThatThing.  That's not what was asked.  This answer is when you know you want to doThatThing, but you may or may not want to lock.

Answer (score 8):

```
bool locked = false;
if (condition) {
    Monitor.Enter(lockObject);
    locked = true;
}
try {
    // possibly critical section
}
finally {
    if (locked) Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
}
```

EDIT: yes, there is a race condition unless you can assure that the condition is constant while threads are entering.

Comment: The point is: it isn't just while entering - if the condition changes, then that probably means that code that hasn't taken a lock is running at risk.

Comment: If you know that all your threads have already entered then it's safe to change the condition. But it's not likely that you'd know that for sure.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to disagree; if the meaning of "condition" is such that the threads should be synchronized, then it has to apply to the entire execution of the critical section - not just the entry point. If any thread entered without a lock, and synchronization becomes needed, you are in trouble.

Comment: Look, it's not a completely thread-safe condition, but in the unlikely event that you know that no more threads will be entering before the rest have cleared the CS you are OK. It's no different from the accepted answer above so it's clear the OP has in fact made such assumptions.

Comment: Oh, I agree it is identical to the accepted answer; I'm just remarking on your point about "entering" - it is wider than that. btw, the downvote isn't from me, but since it matches the accepted, I'll +1 to even it out; so if you check you should be +8 up over all...

Comment: +1. I have a whole bunch of code that should be conditionally locked, where the condition does not change during the life-time of the process (it is a configuration setting read on start up). I am protecting a call to an external system that is currently not thread safe, so I need to synchronise all calls to it. If later the external system is made thread safe, I can change the config and the lock will be removed.

Comment: You can use `Monitor.IsEntered` and remove your `bool`

Answer (score 8):

I'm no threading expert, but it sounds like you might be looking for something like this (double-checked locking). The idea is to check the condition both before and after acquiring the lock.

```
private static object lockHolder = new object();

if (ActionIsValid()) {
  lock(lockHolder) {
    if (ActionIsValid()) {
       DoSomething();    
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, to avoid a race condition, I'd be tempted to use a [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) here - treat concurrent access as a read lock, and exclusive access as a write lock. That way, if the conditions change you won't end up with some inappropriate code still executing blindly in the region (under the false assumption that it is safe); a bit verbose, but
(formatted for space):

```
        if (someCondition) {
            lockObj.EnterReadLock();
            try { Foo(); }
            finally { lockObj.ExitReadLock(); }
        } else {
            lockObj.EnterWriteLock();
            try { Foo(); }
            finally { lockObj.ExitWriteLock(); }
        }
```

Comment: Small addition: This is not possible prior to .NET 3.5, ReaderWriterLockSlim is freshly introduced.

Comment: True; before that there is ReaderWriterLock

Answer (score 3):

If you have many methods/properties that require conditional locking, you don't want to repeat the same pattern over and over again. I propose the following trick:

### Non-repetitive conditional-lock pattern

With a private helper `struct` implementing `IDisposable` we can encapsulate the condition/lock without measurable overhead.

```cs
public void DoStuff()
{
    using (ConditionalLock())
    {
        // Thread-safe code
    }
}
```

It's quite easy to implement. Here's a sample class demonstrating this pattern:

```cs
public class Counter
{
    private static readonly int MAX_COUNT = 100;

    private readonly bool synchronized;
    private int count;
    private readonly object lockObject = new object();

    private int lockCount;

    public Counter(bool synchronized)
    {
        this.synchronized = synchronized;
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            using (ConditionalLock())
            {
                return count;
            }
        }
    }

    public int LockCount
    {
        get
        {
            using (ConditionalLock())
            {
                return lockCount;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Increase()
    {
        using (ConditionalLock())
        {
            if (count < MAX_COUNT)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }

    private LockHelper ConditionalLock() => new LockHelper(this);

    // This is where the magic happens!
    private readonly struct LockHelper : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Counter counter;
        private readonly bool lockTaken;

        public LockHelper(Counter counter)
        {
            this.counter = counter;

            lockTaken = false;
            if (counter.synchronized)
            {
                Monitor.Enter(counter.lockObject, ref lockTaken);
                counter.lockCount++;
            }
        }

        private void Exit()
        {
            if (lockTaken)
            {
                Monitor.Exit(counter.lockObject);
            }
        }

        void IDisposable.Dispose() => Exit();
    }
}
```

Now, let's create a small sample program demonstrating its correctness.

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var onlyOnThisThread = new Counter(synchronized: false);
        IncreaseToMax(c1);

        var onManyThreads = new Counter(synchronized: true);
        var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => IncreaseToMax(c2));
        var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => IncreaseToMax(c2));
        var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => IncreaseToMax(c2));
        Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3);

        Console.WriteLine($"Counter(false) => Count = {c1.Count}, LockCount = {c1.LockCount}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Counter(true)  => Count = {c2.Count}, LockCount = {c2.LockCount}");
    }

    private static void IncreaseToMax(Counter counter)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            counter.Increase();
        }
    }
}
```

### Output:

```
Counter(false) => Count = 100, LockCount = 0
Counter(true)  => Count = 100, LockCount = 3002
```

Now you can let the caller decide whether locking (costly) is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you've got some code that looks a little like this:

```
private Monkey GetScaryMonkey(int numberOfHeads){
    Monkey ape = null;        
    lock(this) {
        ape = new Monkey();
        ape.AddHeads(numberOfHeads);            
    }
    return ape;
}
```

To make this conditional couldn't you just do this:

```
private Monkey GetScaryMonkey(int numberOfHeads){
    if ( numberOfHeads > 1 ) {
         lock(this) {
            return CreateNewMonkey( numberOfHeads );          
        }
    }
    return CreateNewMonkey( numberOfHeads );
}
```

Should work, no?

Comment: lock(this) is bad: 
http://srtsolutions.com/blogs/billwagner/archive/2007/09/09/why-lock-this-is-bad.aspx

Comment: @spoulson - just what I was going to say ;-p

Comment: +1 for mentioning Scary Monkeys, which don't get brought up often enough in modern programming discussions, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Double-checked locking pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_checked_locking_pattern), as suggested above. that's the trick IMO :)

make sure you have your lock object as a *static*, as listed in not.that.dave.foley.myopenid.com's example.