# How to lock a section of code in C# when the Count of a Queue is Zero?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I have a situation where where I need to lock a section of code in C#, when the `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>` has a `Count` of zero. i.e. When it has zero objects in it, a particular section of code should be locked and as soon as its Count increases, the section of code should be unlocked.

```
Queue<WordApplicationWrapper> myQ = new Queue<WordApplicationWrapper>();
lock( if myQ.Count==0 )
{
    app = (WordApplicationWrapper)myQ.Dequeue();
}
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Post some code to show how you use it? I guess `BlockingCollection` will be the best fit.

Comment: why is your code thread synchronization depends on item count? having items in queue and locking code makes a small sense.

Comment: if(queue.Count != 0) {/*your code*/}??and you have not mentioned anywhere if you need it to be thread safe but you have tagged locking,synchronization ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write a conditional lock in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243152/how-can-i-write-a-conditional-lock-in-c)

Comment: why Dequeing when queue count is 0?

Comment: I wrote an algorithm, it is dequeueing if it was able to enter the code section, and that would be possible if Count was >0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BlockingCollection` and `GetConsumingEnumerable` instead.

```
BlockingCollection<WordApplicationWrapper> collection = new BlockingCollection<WordApplicationWrapper>();
foreach (var item in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{

}
```

Above foreach block when there is no item in the collection and starts enumerating when you get one. It will be ended once you called `collection.CompleteAdding()`

Answer (score 1):

It really sounds like you are looking for [BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186(v=vs.110).aspx).

When you `foreach` over the resulting enumerable your code will block while the collection is empty and resume as new entries are added. Note that `BlockingCollection` will use a `ConcurrentQueue` as it's default backing store.

Answer (score 0):

Simple thought, Wrap up your code in a function and call it like this.

```
//obj is your locker object

if (queue.Count ==0)
{
    lock(obj)
    {
         YourCode();
    }
}
else
{
    YourCode();
}
```

Isn't this you want?